# How to perform "copy" / "paste" for a specific record of the table and its child nodes?

Tags: c#, ms-access, ado.net

There is a database table. (MS Access)
On the basis of the table a tree is formed.

field `ID` - autoincrement (formed by the database).

Scenario:
1. User. Selects the node to copy;
2. User. Selects the node where to copy;
3. Program. Gets the string of the node to be copied;
4. Program. Copies the string "2 1 0 AA Node Level_2" and the associated strings as child lines (nodes) into the node "16 13 2 CC Node Level_2", which is specified as "recipient";
5. Program. Updates the database table based on changes to the DataTable.

**Question.**
How to programmatically “copy” and “insert” for a specific record of the table (DataTable) and its child nodes (rows) with any nesting of nodes?
The question means how to perform clause 3, clause 4?

As a result, additional records should appear in the source table.
**ID // PrID // sorting // NodeName // field_1 // field_2 // field_3**
18 16 0 AA Node Level_2
19 18 0 AAA Node Level_3
20 19 0 AAAA Node Level_4
21 19 1 AAAB Node Level_4
23 19 2 AAAC Node Level_4_Изм_3

**Tree based on source table**
[image: Tree based on source table]

```
public void connect()
        {
            string catBD = @"c:\test\visualStudio\csharp\01\01.accdb";
            string conBD = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0}", catBD);

            OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(conBD);

            connection.Open();

            string query1 = "SELECT * FROM TableTreeView_12_0";
            OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand(query1, connection);


            dt = new DataTable();

            adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd1);
            cb = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter);

            adapter.Fill(dt);

        }
```

**Source table**
**ID // PrID // sorting // NodeName // field_1 // field_2 // field_3**
1   0           0   A Node Level_1_изм_2
2   1   0   AA Node  Level_2
3   2   0   AAA Node Level_3
4   3   0   AAAA Node Level_4
5   3   1   AAAB Node Level_4
6   3   2   AAAC Node  Level_4_Изм_3
7   1   1   AB Node Level_2
8   1   2   AC Node Level_2
9   0   1   B Node  Level_1
10  9   0   BA Node  Level_2
11  9   1   BB Node  Level_2
12  9   2   BC Node  Level_2
13  0   2   C Node  Level_1
14  13  0   CA Node  Level_2
15  13  1   CB Node  Level_2
16  13  2   CC Node  Level_2
17  13  3   CD Node  Level_2

Comment: So when the user copies node 2 into node 16 - node 2's PrID changes from 1 to 16, and all the children of node 2 become children of node 16, or do they stay children of node 2?

Comment: @ZoharPeled I updated the question.

Comment: Well, basically you need to duplicate a record, and then repeat this for all the records associated with it. You might have a problem with the auto-increment columns.

Comment: @Zohar Peled `You might have a problem with the auto-increment ..` - Are you talking about `field ID - autoincrement (formed by the database) .`? I made it just by analogy.
Are you talking about `field ID - autoincrement (formed by the database) .`? I made it just by analogy.
1. Option 1. Will it be correct to create an ID in the code?
Example: `ID`-new record = maximum` ID` of table +1.

2. Option 2. Will the scenario be correct:
Scenario: 2.0. we copy "parent". 2.1. save the "parent" in the database; 2.2. obtained from the database `ID`" parent "2.3. assign `ID`" parent "child entries;

Comment: If the `id` column is auto-generated by the database, perhaps it's better to do the entire thing in a stored procedure and re-select. There are ways to ensure correctly handling the auto-increment in code, but without knowing what database you are working with, it's impossible to predict how will it handle newly added rows.

Comment: @Zohar Peled  I am using MSAcess.
I would be grateful if you offer a solution for this issue.

Comment: It's been forever since I've last worked with MS-Access. Therefor I can't offer a solution that will enable you to do it correctly.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I'll figure out something to solve the problem with the ID. Maybe you can tell how to perform "copy" and "embed" for this situation?
Or share links to similar solutions.

Comment: I would rather not post a partial answer. You should be looking at `DataTable.Rows` property - you can get the entire row based on the `Id` column and add a new row using `DataTable.Rows.Add()`. As for the ids, I would suggest using 0 - the source ids number - so you'll get the same number as the source table, but negative. This will ensure you are not using an id already used in the database for your new rows.